# Looking for a large collection of XML files

Tags: xml

Hey, I'm writing a program that I need to test with 1000s of XML files - any idea where I can get some?

Comment: Are you writing an XML parser?

Comment: No. I'm writing a metric spaces Library, and I want to test on Trees.

Comment: Could also use a bunch of "open" Office XML files (.docx, .xlsx, etc).

Comment: Is it important that the test collection exercises a wide range of XML features, e.g. namespaces, comments and processing instructions, mixed content, DTDs, entity references, character encodings, non-BMP data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Google search by filetype yields promising results. Just save a bunch of those pages. A lot of them are RSS feeds.

If you feel up to it, you could write a quick app to scrape the files from Google's search results.

[Google - "< ?xml filetype:xml"](http://www.google.ca/search?q=filetype%3artf&hl=en&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=off&tbs=#sclient=psy&hl=en&lr=&safe=off&q=%3C%3Fxml+filetype%3axml&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=%3C%3Fxml+filetype%3axml&pbx=1&fp=c01024f5a8f55905)

Answer (score 3):

What does your program do?

If you need a particular format, your best bet is probably creating them yourself. You can automate this with a script/simple program.

Actually, creating your own files for testing purposes is likely your best bet in any scenario, since you want to have some control and understanding of your testing inputs in order for the testing to be meaningful.

Comment: That's fine, I have a generator - but I want to test on 'Real World' data

Comment: @robert in which case, you might want to look at finding a public webservice.